# Getting array length in json, Nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following input:

```
{
  "abc": [1,2,3,4,5],
  "ghf": [2,4,6,8]
}
```

In the desired output I wanted to have the array length of these fields.

```
{
   "abc" : 5,
   "ghf" : 4
}
```

Which processors should I be using and how?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation along with a list function called **size** within a ***JoltTransformJSON*** processor such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=size(@(1,&))"
    }
  }
]
```